# How to import Excel to Database using SSIS without changing row order !!?

Tags: database, ssis, business-intelligence, msbi

Actually i am importing EXcel to  Data Base using SSIS

But its changing the Row order so is there any way to  restrict without changing the  row order!

Please don't  give hit (-) if its duplicated question in Stack overflow 
Thanks (+1)

Comment: What makes you think its in a different order? Are you selecting it back out with `SELECT`? There is *no* order in returned records unless you use an `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of rows in the database do not matter. Relational tables are un-ordered sets rather than ordered lists (like Excel). Even if you import the data a certain way into the database, the order of the data is random and can change. If you want the data to appear a certain way, simply use a `SELECT` statement with an `ORDER BY` of your choice.